# How to add one day to the Date object in React or even Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a weekly picker. For the most part it works as intended, I actually get the right week when I click on it, but the selected days within the calendar portion of the picker are displaying a day behind. For example, in the screenshot below, the week picked is `2020-06-08 to 2020-06-14` yyyy-mm-dd format by the way. But as you can see in the picker, it displays the week shifted - 1

I'll post the relevant code but hard as I tried, I couldn't make a codesandbox for you. Way too many dependencies

[image: Notice the days in the labels and the days in the picker]

Here is the convertDate function for the formatting. This is not related to the problem but in case you're wondering what was in it from the main function

```
const convertDate = (date) => {
  let dt = new Date(date);
  var yyyy = dt.getFullYear();
  var mm = dt.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = dt.getDate();

  return `${yyyy}-${(mm > 9 ? '' : '0') + mm}-${(dd > 9 ? '' : '0') + dd}`;
};
```

And this the actual function that renders the days in the picker

**EDIT (with help  from Sergei**

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  setDate(new Date(date.setDate(e.target.id)));
  
  // added this to calculate the offset to my local timezone
  let localDate = new Date(date.setDate(e.target.id));
  var localoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  var timeZoneFromDB = -4.00;
  var tzDifference = timeZoneFromDB * localoffset + localDate.getTimezoneOffset();
  var offsetTime = new Date(localDate.getTime() + tzDifference * localoffset * 1000);

  const firstDay = new Date(
    offsetTime.setDate(offsetTime.getDate() - offsetTime.getDay() + 1)
  );
  const lastDay = new Date(
    offsetTime.setDate(offsetTime.getDate() - offsetTime.getDay() + 7)
  );

  setWeek({ firstDay, lastDay });

  const value = e.target.value;
  setState({
    ...state, 
    [e.target.name]: value,
    startdate: convertDate(firstDay), 
    enddate: convertDate(lastDay)
  }) 
};

const renderDays = () => {
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let ar = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= days[month]; i++) {
    let currentDate = new Date(date).setDate(i);

    let cName = "single-number ";
    if (
      new Date(state.startdate).getTime() <= new Date(currentDate).getTime() &&
      new Date(currentDate).getTime() <= new Date(state.enddate).getTime() 
    ) {
      cName = cName + "selected-week";4

      console.clear();
      console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
      console.log("start date: ", new Date(state.startdate).getTime());
      console.log("converted start date: ", convertDate(new Date(state.startdate).getTime()));
      console.log("current date: ", new Date(currentDate).getTime());
      console.log("converted current date: ", convertDate(new Date(currentDate).getTime()));
      console.log("end date: ", new Date(state.enddate).getTime());
      console.log("converted end date: ", convertDate(new Date(state.enddate).getTime()));

    }

    ar.push(
      <div key={v4()} id={i} className={cName} onClick={handleClick}>
        {i}
      </div>
    );
  }

  const displayDate = new Date(date).setDate(1);
  let dayInTheWeek = new Date(displayDate).getDay();

  let empty = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < dayInTheWeek; i++) {
    empty.push(<div key={v4()} id={i} className="single-number empty"></div>);
  }

  return [...empty, ...ar];
};
```

Here's a pic of what I am console.logging so you can see that I am capturing the intended dates (ignore the undefined). This is the state being console logged in the `useEffect()` But also check out the individual logs from within the `renderDays()`. They're a day behind

[image]

**I just need the days in the picker to + 1 in the view** Thanks in advanced you for your help

Comment: I tried to reproduce (and simplify a bit) your issue, but im not able to reproduce it as is, without seeing `handleClick` probably,, Question is how your `date` object is set. Now why: because `1591574400000` that you see in console will be 2020-06-08 `00:00` for GMT and for any UTC > 0, but if your timezone is negative - you will get what you see. Methods like `dt.getFullYear()` and `getMonth` and `getDate` returns values using your OS `local time`. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-andras-wlhtti?file=/src/App.js:888-895)

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense. Is there ant workaround to generalize it to negative timezones only? This is going to be used in the USA only

Comment: @SergeySosunov I added the handleCLick function for clarity

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Be very careful of using `new Date(string)` to parse date values; [it rarely ends well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).

Comment: How do I show the console log without running code?

Comment: I got it working with a tiny issue that will most likely not get caught in testing lol I'll take my chances lol. Thanks guys. I credited you both

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Sergei and Heretic in the comments I was able to get it to work by adding the following helper function outside of the main view object

```
function addDays(date, days) {
   var result = new Date(date);
   result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
   return result;
}
```

Then I updated my render function to conditionally check this way

```
let currentTime = new Date(currentDate).getTime()
let startdayinview = new Date(state.startdate).getTime()
let enddayinview = new Date(state.enddate).getTime()

if (
  addDays(startdayinview, -1) <= addDays(currentTime, -2) &&
  addDays(currentTime, 0) <= addDays(enddayinview, 1) 
) {
  cName = cName + "selected-week";
}
```

As Heretic mentioned, the Date object is not ideal, but we gotta work with what we're given!

Comment: Patching, but dont shoot your leg one day with it :)

Comment: As long as it adds a real day and not just a number (i.e. 8-31 to 9-1 instead of 8-31 to 8-32 ) I'm ok with it lol